# Logitech MX Ergo Scroll wheel doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, macos

Whether or not I have scroll direction "natural" checked or not, when I use my mouse wheel to scroll nothing happens. I can scroll with two fingers on the trackpack but turning of the mouse wheel of the MX Ergo that I linked via bluetooth gets ignored.

I have installed Logitech Options and can successfully map actions to mouse buttons with it.

Is there anyway to get mousewheel scrolling on my MacBook Pro 2018?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to give the Logitech Option Dameon the ability to control my computer in System Preferences -> Security&Privacy -> Accessibility -> Privacy

Answer (score 0):

Needed to give **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Accessibility** > **Privacy** access to "Logi Options Daemon" *and* "Logi Options".